# How to use \pdffontobjnum?

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I want to get the internal PDF object number of the current font in use.

pdfTeX provides the primitive `\pdffontobjnum` which requires a font name as an argument. I have no clue what is expected as font name, e. g. something like `cmr`?

Whatever I try, I get a `! Missing font identifier.` error.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Test.

\pdffontobjnum\rmdefault

\end{document}
```

So my question is, how to get a valid font name to be passed as an argument to `\pdffontobjnum`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `\font` to get the current font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Test.

\pdffontobjnum\font

\textit{\pdffontobjnum\font}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

A *font identifier* is a control sequence corresponding to a font selection; it must be defined with the primitive `\font` (or `\let` to a control sequence so defined).

However, there are two predefined font identifiers. The first is `\nullfont`, which is not particularly useful because it has no characters. The second one is much more interesting and is `\font` itself.

Whenever TeX is looking for a font identifier, if it finds `\font` it will do as if you have used a font identifier corresponding to the current font.

In LaTeX the font identifiers are built in a standard format

```
\<encoding>/<family>/<series>/<shape>/<size>
```

so, for example, `\OT1/cmr/m/n/10` refers to the default font. However, these identifiers are only built on demand when a `\selectfont` command is issued and points to the desired font; thus something like

```
\expandafter\pdffontobjnum\csname OT1/cmr/m/it/10\endcsname
```

might produce a `Missing font identifier` error, if the font hasn't yet been selected in the document. So you need to select the font before using `\pdffontobjnum` anyway.

The problem of identifiers only built on demand is not the main one. Consider the following plain TeX example:

```
\edef\tenitnumber{\pdffontobjnum\tenit}
\message{The font number is \tenitnumber}

\tenitnumber

\bye
```

This will cause a low level fatal error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./alfon.tex{/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.m
ap} The font number is 1 [1]Assertion failed: (fo->last_char >= fo->first_char), function create_fontdictionary, file ../../../texk/web2c/pdftexdir/writefont.c, line 607.
 )Abort trap: 6
```

because the internal number points to an object that's apparently not created. No error if you add `\it` before `\tenitnumber`, so the font is actually used in the document. It's not sufficient to use the font in a box: indeed

```
\edef\tenitnumber{\pdffontobjnum\tenit}
\message{The font number is \tenitnumber}

\setbox0=\hbox{\tenit something}    
\tenitnumber

\bye
```

would fail in the same way. So you *must* typeset something in a font, if you want to store the object number corresponding to it.

The error doesn't happen with LuaTeX; for instance,

```
\edef\firstfont{\pdffeedback fontobjnum\tenit}
\firstfont

\bye
```

correctly prints 1 and `pdffonts` outputs

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
SDXKYB+CMR10                         Type 1            yes yes no       5  0
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. This is what I expected, the font object is inserted into the PDF output and hence its object number is valid if only it has been used before by typesetting something. Finally I want to use the current text font within text fields in a PDF form, by adding the font object as a resource to the `/AcroForm` dictionary in the PDF Catalog. Unfortunately this did not work, producing a warning in AR and showing only dots in the TextField. But this might become another question here.

Comment: @AlexG we're on the same quest for embedding LaTeX fonts (Type1) inside the `/AcroForm`? Do you have any insight or get it to work finally?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Results of my experimenting with fonts in PDF forms: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449681